# Configurar WebJob Azure para executar a cada 15 minutos

Tags: microsoft-azure

Boa tarde, estou tentando publicar um WebJob no azure para executar a cada 15 minutos.

Estou publicando diretamente pelo visual studio e já coloquei o arquivo settings.job.

O meu problema é que quando eu coloco para executar a cada 3 minutos funciona certinho, mas quando coloco 15 minutos, ele só funciona nas horas cheias (0,15,30,45).

Segue como está meu arquivo settings.job:

> { "schedule": "0 0/15 * * * *" }

Answer (score 0):

Hoje a recomendação é usar Azure Functions com Time Trigger.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer